# npm start shows no error but blank screen

Tags: reactjs

I created a react app using `npx create-react-app ./`
then I deleted my src folder and created src folder again. then I created index.js with following codes

```
import react from 'react'
import { ReactDOM } from 'react'

import App from './App'
ReactDOM.render(<App/>,document.getElementById('root'));
```

Then created App.js file with following codes

```
import React from 'react'

const app = () => {
  return (
    <div className='App'>
        <h1>Hello</h1>
      
    </div>
  )
}

export default app
```

Then saving those files in terminal I started the app. `npm start`
this loades the react app in localhost:3000 but it shows a white screen only.

please help me solving this problem.

I want this code shows Hello

Comment: Can you provide your index.html file?